# Pandas reshape dataframe values as columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am struggling with a problem.

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
month      code     a     b     c
2018-01-01  foo     43   34324  12
2018-01-01  bar     232  34     634
2018-01-01  gar     2312 454    243
2017-01-01  foo     12   1234   34534
2017-01-01  bar     32   34232  345
2017-01-01  gar     2323 34     234
2016-01-01  foo     908  759    342
2016-01-01  bar     4654 42     865
2016-01-01  foo     3    43    34235
```

I am trying to reshape my dataframe so columns 'a', 'b' and 'c' are transposed and grouped by unique months as the columns. Then I need to sum my values. I am looking for something like this:

```
   2016-01-01 2017-01-01 2018-01-01
a
b
c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need

```
df.groupby('month').sum().T
```

#### Explanation:

1. Group by unique month.
2. Within each group, take the `sum` of each column, which by default will select only columns with numeric data types. That's why the column `code` does not end up in the result.
3. Transpose the result with `.T`